# Python Parse log file in realtime, reload when the log rotates

Tags: python

I have this code which continuously tail the `access.log` and parse events. But during the log rotation, `access.log` will be moved to `access.log.timestamp` and a new `access.log` will be created by the java process. When this rejig occurs the python parser won't parse the new `access.log`. Pls help with some clues how can I reload the program upon it's file change.

```
with open('/var/log/app/access.log') as f:
   while True:
     line = f.readline()
     if line:
      process(line)
```

Comment: What you mean by *python parser won't parse the new access.log*? Do you get any error?

Comment: Use a flag to mark the log is rotated or not?

Comment: @Kasramvd, No, the process just goes non responsible. No errors.

Comment: I suggest to use the python `Logging handlers` which provided a lot of useful tools for dealing with log files, specially [`RotatingFileHandler`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#rotatingfilehandler) class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the issue seems to be python file pointer maintaining its positional reference on log change. So what we will do is check size of file when it is less than before we will reset python file pointer to start i.e '0' using seek(0). I have not tired this code yet you can get back with result, so we can modify the same.

```
import os

file_path = '/var/log/app/access.log'

with open(file_path) as f:
    file_size = 0
    while True:
        line = f.readline()
        if line:
            print line
        file_status_obj = os.stat(file_path)
        if file_size < file_status_obj.st_size:
            f.seek(0)
        file_size = file_status_obj.st_size
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Cool, now the code is exiting when the file is moved. Now I can go on. Thanks !

Comment: great to hear that @ManivG

Answer (score 1):

- You should handle the catching up of EOF when the log file may have more lines some times later.
- You can add a signal handler to make your code close and open the file again, eg executed by logrotate (on RHEL)
- If you cannot signal this log processor, you can check the inode of the file. This works if your log rotate is NOT copy & truncate.

Something similar to this, please check all necessary exception handling. This is a partial copy of my working system:

```
def iNodeOf(file):
  if os.path.exists(file):
    s = os.stat(file)
    return s.st_ino
  else:
    return -1

while True:
  iReload = False
  fileInode = iNodeOf(conf.LOGFILE)
  f = open(conf.LOGFILE, 'r')
  countDown = 15
  while (not iReload) and (countDown > 0):
    # seek to current position again
    f.seek(0,1)
    while countDown > 0:
      filePos = f.tell()
      line = f.readline()
      if line:
          process(line)
          countDown = 15
      else:
          countDown -= 1
          time.sleep(1)
    newInode = iNodeOf(conf.LOGFILE)
    if (fileInode == newInode):
      # file not changed, sleep, seek from BOF, and try again
      time.sleep(5)
      f.seek(filePos,0)
      countDown = 15
    else:
      # file changed
      f.close()
      iReload = True
```